# ClickOnce deletes my local database when it updates.. how not to?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce to deploy my application. When the app runs the first time, if a db doesn't exist, it creates one.

Problem is, when I update, it removes the local database. Is there a way to tell it to ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you're putting it in the applications directory...  don't!

Put it in `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`.

Comment: Are there any security concerns I need to take into account? Does the app by default have access to write to files outside the application folder?

Comment: By default, an application can write to ApplicationData and LocalApplicationData.  Obviously, an admin or user can change the permissions on these folders at any time - but I think it is a "safe" assumption that you can write there.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the database in the deployment. Implement your own db creation (using script) when the database isn't present.

Comment: I already am - it's not part of deployment, yet it gets removed if an update occurs.

Comment: +1. Good answer..  And be sure to put it in a place where it will be accessible, such as Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData as answered by @Phillip

Answer (score 0):

In the project's Publish options, under Application Files, is the database file's Publish status set to Data File?

Comment: The database file is actually accessed by a class project, so it doesn't show up in the Application Files area of the publish options.