# How can I upgrade a deployed sql database?

Tags: .net, database, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ClickOnce deletes my local database when it updates.. how not to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690444/clickonce-deletes-my-local-database-when-it-updates-how-not-to)

I have deployed an application using clickonce which contains a sql database management schema. On application start up, the application attempts to synchronize a local database with a server database. I have deployed the application and this works great, however, since I have deployed the application I have made various changes to the database schema as well as the wpf application. I am now trying to deploy the upgrade and have not been able to get the new database to deploy correctly. What seems to happen, is the start up database sync fails and the application then points to a null database allowing me to do absolutely nothing. I am in much need of help. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690444/clickonce-deletes-my-local-database-when-it-updates-how-not-to

Comment: After much debugging, I have found that the database is getting populated correctly, however I'm getting an entity framework exception from a query I am doing on the database. This exception doesn't occur in development mode. Thoughts?

Comment: Ask a new question about that one.  Post a short code snippet that reproduces the problem.